# Magento page is very slow

Tags: performance, magento, indexing

I have a Magento shop: www.ihnkenrollen.de

The page itself loads quite fast but as soon as i click on a category on the left, it takes 6-10 seconds to load. Someone told me that the shop uses no index what makes the shop really slow. How can I add an index to my shop? What else could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: activate the cache, depend on your internet connection, depend on your images size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enable flat Catalog** for Category and prodcuts in

**System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Frontend**

[image]

Also add **Lesti FPC cache** (look to configure it for filters)
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lesti-fpc-simple-fullpagecache.html

and **edit htaccess** file (memory limit, html and files compression, files expiration etc.).